# python visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio

i have 2 Errors when i try to debug my python program

1.Failed to launch the Python Process, please validate the path 'python'
2.Linter pylint is not installed

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PySpark",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "osx": {
                "pythonPath": "${env:SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit"
            },
            "windows": {
                "pythonPath": "${env:SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit.cmd"
            },
            "linux": {
                "pythonPath": "${env:SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit"
            },
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python Module",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "module": "module.name",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Integrated Terminal/Console",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "External Terminal/Console",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "",
            "console": "externalTerminal",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/manage.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload"
            ],
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput",
                "DjangoDebugging"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "fully qualified path fo 'flask' executable. Generally located along with python interpreter",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceRoot}/quickstart/app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Flask (old)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/run.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [],
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Pyramid",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/development.ini"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput",
                "Pyramid"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Watson",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/console.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "args": [
                "dev",
                "runserver",
                "--noreload=True"
            ],
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach (Remote Debug)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 3000,
            "secret": "my_secret",
            "host": "localhost"
        }
    ]
}
```

https://puu.sh/wmZ4u/17eceffcba.png

it says i miss these two things how do I fix this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should change `${config:python.pythonPath}` to your Python path. If you are using Linux/Mac, you could try `which python`.
2. You need to install pylint, run `pip install pylint`